# Get excel row as TXT string

Tags: excel, delphi

Delphi XE10. I need to read row by row from an Excel worksheet as a (tab-separated) string. What you get when you use 'select a row - copy - paste in Notepad'. The worksheet contains strings, numbers and dates in various formats.
What works is this:

```
function TexcelSource.nextRow: string;
var k : integer;
begin
  result:=sheet.cells.items[currentRow,1].text;
  for k:=2 to maxCol do
      result:=result+tab+sheet.cells.items[currentRow,k].text;
  inc(currentRow)
end;
```

where sheet is the reference to an excel worksheet (var Variant):

```
XLApp:=createOLEobject('excel.application');
XLApp.Workbooks.open(filename) ;
Sheet:=XLApp.WorkSheets[1] ;
MaxRow:=Sheet.Usedrange.EntireRow.count ;
MaxCol:=sheet.Usedrange.EntireColumn.count;
```

However, it is unacceptably slow. I have tried to import the whole sheet as an array in one step and read from the array:

```
sheetData:=Sheet.UsedRange.Value;
```

This is fast enough but I can't get all sheetData[row,col] as a string value. It returns cells with string value but stops at a cell with an integer value with error 'Could not convert variant of type (UnicodeString) into type (Double)'. (VarType of that element seems to be vtPointer - which I do not understand; neither do I understand the error.)

I have also tried copy and paste via the Delphi Clipboard. Works for a while and then the clipboard becomes unavailable. Anyway, that is not an approach I like for an operational system.

I would welcome suggestions on how to read a worksheet row as a string with acceptable performance.

Comment: Which Excel version?

Comment: There's no such thing as XE10, FWIW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading a range in one go is the way to do it (as you already have tried):

```
sheetData := Sheet.UsedRange.Value;
```

I can reproduce the error you get if I concatenate the `sheetData` elements directly in a loop. I did not investigate the cause of the error.

However, there is no error if each element is first assigned to a `string` variable, and that variable is then concatenated. So the following workaround with a temporary string variable, `tmpstr`, works for various numerical values:

```
for row := ...
begin
  rowstr := sheetData[row, 1];
  for col := 2 to ...
  begin  
    tmpstr := sheetData[row, col];
    rowstr := rowstr + tab + tmpstr;
  end;
  // use rowstr as needed
end;
```

---

A "cleaner" way to convert any cell value to string, is to use the `VarToStr()` function, which has existed at least from Delphi 7.

```
for row := ...
begin
  rowstr := sheetData[row, 1];
  for col := 2 to ...
    rowstr := rowstr + tab + VarToStr(sheetData[row, col]);
  // use rowstr as needed
end;
```